# Can't install gevent OSX 10.11

Tags: macos

Trying to install gevent using Homebrew on OSX 10.11 latest public beta. When running the install, it outputs the following errors (Sorry for the large wall of code, not sure exactly where the error is)

```
    clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I /opt/local/include -L /opt/local/lib -U__llvm__ -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/libev -Ilibev -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c gevent/gevent.core.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/gevent/gevent.core.o
  clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/opt/local/lib'
  In file included from gevent/gevent.core.c:249:
  In file included from gevent/libev.h:2:
  libev/ev.c:483:48: warning: '/*' within block comment [-Wcomment]
  /*#define MIN_INTERVAL  0.00000095367431640625 /* 1/2**20, good till 2200 */
                                                 ^
  libev/ev.c:1029:42: error: '_Noreturn' keyword must precede function declarator
    ecb_inline void ecb_unreachable (void) ecb_noreturn;
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    _Noreturn
  libev/ev.c:832:26: note: expanded from macro 'ecb_noreturn'
    #define ecb_noreturn   _Noreturn
                           ^
  libev/ev.c:1625:31: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    EV_API_DECL struct ev_loop *ev_default_loop_ptr = 0; /* needs to be initialised to make it a definition despite extern */
                                ^
  libev/ev.c:1796:7: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
        array_needsize (ANPENDING, pendings [pri], pendingmax [pri], w_->pending, EMPTY2);
        ^
  libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
        int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                       ^
  libev/ev.c:1807:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
    array_needsize (W, rfeeds, rfeedmax, rfeedcnt + 1, EMPTY2);
    ^
  libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
        int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                       ^
  libev/ev.c:1934:7: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
        array_needsize (int, fdchanges, fdchangemax, fdchangecnt, EMPTY2);
        ^
  libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
        int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                       ^
  In file included from gevent/gevent.core.c:249:
  In file included from gevent/libev.h:2:
  In file included from libev/ev.c:2484:
  libev/ev_kqueue.c:50:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
    array_needsize (struct kevent, kqueue_changes, kqueue_changemax, kqueue_changecnt, EMPTY2);
    ^
  libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
        int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                       ^
  In file included from gevent/gevent.core.c:249:
  In file included from gevent/libev.h:2:
  In file included from libev/ev.c:2490:
  libev/ev_poll.c:66:7: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
        array_needsize (struct pollfd, polls, pollmax, pollcnt, EMPTY2);
        ^
  libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
        int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                       ^
  libev/ev.c:3648:34: warning: '&' within '|' [-Wbitwise-op-parentheses]
    fd_change (EV_A_ fd, w->events & EV__IOFDSET | EV_ANFD_REIFY);
                         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~
  libev/ev.c:3648:34: note: place parentheses around the '&' expression to silence this warning
    fd_change (EV_A_ fd, w->events & EV__IOFDSET | EV_ANFD_REIFY);
                                   ^
                         (                      )
  libev/ev.c:3687:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
    array_needsize (ANHE, timers, timermax, ev_active (w) + 1, EMPTY2);
    ^
  libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
        int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                       ^
  libev/ev.c:4367:5: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
      array_needsize (ev_idle *, idles [ABSPRI (w)], idlemax [ABSPRI (w)], active, EMPTY2);
      ^
  libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
        int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                       ^
  libev/ev.c:4407:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
    array_needsize (ev_prepare *, prepares, preparemax, preparecnt, EMPTY2);
    ^
  libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
        int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                       ^
  libev/ev.c:4445:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
    array_needsize (ev_check *, checks, checkmax, checkcnt, EMPTY2);
    ^
  libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
        int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                       ^
  libev/ev.c:4592:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
    array_needsize (ev_fork *, forks, forkmax, forkcnt, EMPTY2);
    ^
  libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
        int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                       ^
  libev/ev.c:4675:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
    array_needsize (ev_async *, asyncs, asyncmax, asynccnt, EMPTY2);
    ^
  libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
        int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                       ^
  14 warnings and 1 error generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for gevent
Failed to build gevent
Installing collected packages: gevent
  Running setup.py install for gevent
    Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/q8/1c24n_wj6kzc6kgl7629pwyh0000gn/T/pip-build-3zCPVx/gevent/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/q8/1c24n_wj6kzc6kgl7629pwyh0000gn/T/pip-9VpZCX-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'gevent.core' extension
    clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I /opt/local/include -L /opt/local/lib -U__llvm__ -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/libev -Ilibev -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c gevent/gevent.core.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/gevent/gevent.core.o
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/opt/local/lib'
    In file included from gevent/gevent.core.c:249:
    In file included from gevent/libev.h:2:
    libev/ev.c:483:48: warning: '/*' within block comment [-Wcomment]
    /*#define MIN_INTERVAL  0.00000095367431640625 /* 1/2**20, good till 2200 */
                                                   ^
    libev/ev.c:1029:42: error: '_Noreturn' keyword must precede function declarator
      ecb_inline void ecb_unreachable (void) ecb_noreturn;
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      _Noreturn
    libev/ev.c:832:26: note: expanded from macro 'ecb_noreturn'
      #define ecb_noreturn   _Noreturn
                             ^
    libev/ev.c:1625:31: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
      EV_API_DECL struct ev_loop *ev_default_loop_ptr = 0; /* needs to be initialised to make it a definition despite extern */
                                  ^
    libev/ev.c:1796:7: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
          array_needsize (ANPENDING, pendings [pri], pendingmax [pri], w_->pending, EMPTY2);
          ^
    libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
          int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                         ^
    libev/ev.c:1807:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
      array_needsize (W, rfeeds, rfeedmax, rfeedcnt + 1, EMPTY2);
      ^
    libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
          int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                         ^
    libev/ev.c:1934:7: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
          array_needsize (int, fdchanges, fdchangemax, fdchangecnt, EMPTY2);
          ^
    libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
          int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                         ^
    In file included from gevent/gevent.core.c:249:
    In file included from gevent/libev.h:2:
    In file included from libev/ev.c:2484:
    libev/ev_kqueue.c:50:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
      array_needsize (struct kevent, kqueue_changes, kqueue_changemax, kqueue_changecnt, EMPTY2);
      ^
    libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
          int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                         ^
    In file included from gevent/gevent.core.c:249:
    In file included from gevent/libev.h:2:
    In file included from libev/ev.c:2490:
    libev/ev_poll.c:66:7: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
          array_needsize (struct pollfd, polls, pollmax, pollcnt, EMPTY2);
          ^
    libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
          int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                         ^
    libev/ev.c:3648:34: warning: '&' within '|' [-Wbitwise-op-parentheses]
      fd_change (EV_A_ fd, w->events & EV__IOFDSET | EV_ANFD_REIFY);
                           ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~
    libev/ev.c:3648:34: note: place parentheses around the '&' expression to silence this warning
      fd_change (EV_A_ fd, w->events & EV__IOFDSET | EV_ANFD_REIFY);
                                     ^
                           (                      )
    libev/ev.c:3687:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
      array_needsize (ANHE, timers, timermax, ev_active (w) + 1, EMPTY2);
      ^
    libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
          int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                         ^
    libev/ev.c:4367:5: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
        array_needsize (ev_idle *, idles [ABSPRI (w)], idlemax [ABSPRI (w)], active, EMPTY2);
        ^
    libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
          int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                         ^
    libev/ev.c:4407:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
      array_needsize (ev_prepare *, prepares, preparemax, preparecnt, EMPTY2);
      ^
    libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
          int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                         ^
    libev/ev.c:4445:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
      array_needsize (ev_check *, checks, checkmax, checkcnt, EMPTY2);
      ^
    libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
          int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                         ^
    libev/ev.c:4592:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
      array_needsize (ev_fork *, forks, forkmax, forkcnt, EMPTY2);
      ^
    libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
          int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                         ^
    libev/ev.c:4675:3: warning: unused variable 'ocur_' [-Wunused-variable]
      array_needsize (ev_async *, asyncs, asyncmax, asynccnt, EMPTY2);
      ^
    libev/ev.c:1758:22: note: expanded from macro 'array_needsize'
          int ecb_unused ocur_ = (cur);                                     \
                         ^
    14 warnings and 1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/q8/1c24n_wj6kzc6kgl7629pwyh0000gn/T/pip-build-3zCPVx/gevent/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/q8/1c24n_wj6kzc6kgl7629pwyh0000gn/T/pip-9VpZCX-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/q8/1c24n_wj6kzc6kgl7629pwyh0000gn/T/pip-build-3zCPVx/gevent
```

Answer (score 99):

use `CFLAGS='-std=c99' pip install gevent` to fix this.

on OS X 10.11, clang uses c11 as the default, so just turn it back to c99.

Comment: I have 10.10.5, could not install gevent, and this resolved my issue.

Comment: good lord this was driving me nuts on OSX 10.10.5, same issue, and setting CFLAGS as root and install `gevent` did the trick-- thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I just had to explicitly add version to the gevent like so CFLAGS='-std=c99' pip install gevent==1.1rc1.

Comment: Please. Best answer this. And then again. And then again.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same issue on my OSX 10.10.5, trying to install [flask-socketio](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO), which has gevent as a dependency, but:

```
sudo CFLAGS='-std=c99' pip install flask-socketio
```

gave me

```
Successfully installed flask-socketio-0.6.0 gevent-1.0.2 gevent-socketio-0.3.6 gevent-websocket-0.9.5
```

So, tonicbupt's answer worked for this too.

Comment: On 10.11 and I had to use `sudo CFLAGS='-std=c99' pip install flask-socketio --no-use-wheel` to get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

I wasted my time for two days and the solution below for Mac users...

```
pip install gevent==1.1b5
```

Solution: [gevent fails to install in a python virtual environment on OS X Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040029/gevent-fails-to-install-in-a-python-virtual-environment-on-os-x-capitan)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10647395)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Just ` pip install gevent==1.1b5` solved my problem. I don't think it is a "link-only" answer.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X El Capitan, I had to do both of the things that were mentioned in the earlier answers, set the CFLAGS variable and downgrade gevent, but I had to use version 1.0 to get the compiler errors to clear.

```
CFLAGS='-std=c99' pip install gevent==1.0
```

Comment: 1.0.2 is OK on el Capitan, with the CFLAGS as above, but the C compiler does produce quite a few warings

Answer (score 1):

As described in its [PyPI instruction](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent),

`pip install --pre gevent`

should install a release candidate version (`1.1rc4` as of Feb 22, 2016) that works for OS X 10.11.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, gevent 1.1.0 final is released in the form of a binary wheel for OS X, and pip will install it by default. A binary wheel for gevent 1.0.2 for OS X is also available for those that cannot upgrade to the newer version. Both of these have been tested to install on OS X 10.11 with the Python 2.6 and 2.7 that Apple distributes, as well as the 2.7 Python downloaded from python.org. (If you have trouble installing binary wheels, you may need to update your version of pip.)

So there shouldn't be any need to set any special CFLAGS anymore unless you must compile 1.0.2 from source. (1.1.0 does not suffer from this problem.)

Note that the wheels are distributed for "narrow" unicode builds of Python, so if you're using a "wide" build, you'll need to compile from source. In that case, setting CFLAGS="--std=c99" is required for gevent 1.0.2 (but not 1.1.0.)